# How to organize related temporal and fixed data in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know how I can achieve this data structure in Firestore.

I have this structure:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- liturgia (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- lh (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- oficio (collection)
   |                |
   |                --- 03070101 (documents)
   |                        |
   |                        --- himno: "Today himno for today oficio"
   |                        |
   |                        --- read: "Today read for today oficio"
   |
   |                --- 03070102 (documents)
   |                        |
   |                        --- himno: "Today himno for today oficio"
   |                        |
   |                        --- read: "Today read for today oficio"
   |
   |                --- 09070325 (documents)
   |                        |
   |                        --- himno: "Today himno for today oficio"
   |                        |
   |                        --- read: "Today read for today oficio"
   |
   |          --- laudes (collection)
   |                |
   |                --- 03070101 (documents)
   |                        |
   |                        --- himno: "Today himno for today laudes"
   |                        |
   |                        --- read: "Today read for today laudes"
   |
   |                --- 03070102 (documents)
   |                        |
   |                        --- himno: "Today himno for today laudes"
   |                        |
   |                        --- read: "Today read for today laudes"
   |
   |                --- 09070325 (documents)
   |                        |
   |                        --- himno: "Today himno for today laudes"
   |                        |
   |                        --- read: "Today read for today laudes"
```

In `oficio` or in `laudes` there are documents **with fixed content**, this content never change, and I need to use that content according to the date.

For example:

I have any date, on this date, one entire content is needed. For example, when I need to show the today content for `oficio`  (or for `laudes`):

- For `2019-03-25`  i will need the content of `09070325`
- For `2019-03-26`  i will need the content of `03070102`

  ...
- For `2020-03-25`  i will need the content of `09070325`
- For `2020-03-26`  i will need the content of `03070103`

  ...
- For `2021-03-25`  i will need the content of `03070101`

I think of a structure to relate the fixed content according to the dates, but I do not know how to do it.

In my application, the current date will be taken, and based on this data, must find the fixed content for `oficio`, for `laudes`, etc.

For example, in `2019-03-25` and in `2020-03-25` is needed the content `09070325`, but in `2021-03-25` is needed the content `03070101`:

```
20190325
    oficio : 09070325
    laudes : 09070325

20190326
    oficio : 03070102
    laudes : 03070102

20200325
    oficio : 03070101
    laudes : 03070101

20210325
    oficio : 03070101
    laudes : 03070101
```

How can I organize my data structure to:

- not having to update the **fixed** content documents
- put in relation the fixed content with **the dates each year**
- obtain the **fixed content according to a given date consuming the least amount of resources**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to use a `date` property of type String for each of your documents and simplify your structure a little bit. So a possible structure might be:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- liturgia (collection)
         |
         --- 03070101 (document)
              |
              --- himno: "Today himno for today oficio"
              |
              --- read: "Today read for today oficio"
              |
              --- date: "20190325"
              |
              --- length: "1h"
```

To get today's document, simply use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference liturgiaRef = rootRef.collection("liturgia");
Query query = liturgiaRef.whereEqualTo("date", today);
```

In which today is `20190325`. That's it!

**Edit:**

According to your comment, instead of storing the data as `date: "20190325"` store it only as `date: "0325"`. This means that you can query according to the month and day no matter what the year is. In this case, today is only `0325`. This way it will work for evey year.

**Edit2:**

According to OP's comments, we agree that a possible solution would be to create a calendar node that relates the dates and the contents.

Comment: Alex thanks for your response. Why you add one field called `lenght` with the value: `lh`? The `lh` node is one part of `liturgia`. Your solution is great but i think to maintain each node updated **each year** (i will be need the `03070101` document at `20210325` but at `2019` and `2020`i will be need `09070325`). Another solution i think now is maintain one `calendar` node with each date and the related document. I can have this `calendar` node synched with the app and save this info as JSON in the app. Then i can read this JSON to take the reference of each day.

Comment: If `1h` is mandatory you can get back and use a schema with a collection and a subcollection. Yes, you right, it's hard to maintain every year. For that, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Alex the problem is not the year only, if you read at end of my question i show some use cases: in `2019-03-25` and in `2020-03-25` i will be need the content of `09010325` document, but in `2021-03-25` i will be need the content of `03070101` I don't know if it's clair: **the content is always the same, but depending of the year i can need different content for one day**. For that i think to store the fixed content (and not update this never)  and maintain another node (as a calendar)  to manage the relations for each date.

Comment: In that case you should use (as you say a calendar) and for each document store a reference to the correct document.

Comment: I think that is the simplest solution. I have one doubt about this, i don't know if is subject for another question. If i decided this solution and i create one node `calendar` that i sync with mi App to store this data off-line, each time one user read this content (off-line) that is count as one connection and read to be billed? I try to avoid two connections for obtain the content.

Comment: As long as the data stays unchanged (and you say it will), you'll be billed only once. The second time you'll get the data from the cache. Reading data from cache does not have cost.

Comment: Alex, your answer has helped me a lot, but I think you should have a note saying that a possible solution would be through a calendar node that relates the dates and the contents. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Updated the question again. You're welcome, cheers!